# undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass - Stripe issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm currently trying to set up a payment option on my patform (part of the tutorial) through stripe. For some reason I'm getting the Nil Class error on the /add_card page when someone enters the card details in and clicks the button ADD. Not sure what am I doing wrong here.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

[image]

**Users_Controller**

```
def add_card
        if current_user.stripe_id.blank?
          customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
            email: current_user.email
          )
          current_user.stripe_id = customer.id
          current_user.save
          #customer.sources.create(source: params[:stripeToken])
        else
          customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(current_user.stripe_id)
        end

        # Add Credit Card to Stripe
        month, year = params[:expiry].split(/ \/ /)
        new_token = Stripe::Token.create(:card =>{
            :number => params[:number],
            :exp_month => month,
            :exp_year => year,
            :cvc => params[:cvv]
        })
        customer.sources.create(source: new_token.id)

    flash[:notice] = "Your card is saved."
    redirect_to payment_method_path
    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
    flash[:alert] = e.message
    redirect_to payment_method_path
    end
```

**Payment Form**

```
<div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">Payment Method</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="container">
          <div class='card' style="margin-bottom: 20px"></div>
          <%= form_tag("/add_card", method: "post", id: "add-card") do %>

                <div class="row pull-center">
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="well">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8 form-group">
                          <label>Card Number</label>
                          <input type="text" name="number" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                          <label>Expiration</label>
                          <input type="text" placeholder="MM/YY" name="expriry" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8 form-group">
                          <label>Name</label>
                          <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                          <label>CVV</label>
                          <input type="text" name="cvv" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 text right"></div>
                        <% if current_user.stripe_id.blank? %>
                          <button class="btn btn-normal btn-block">Addd Card</button>
                        <% else %>
                          <button class="btn btn-normal btn-block">Update Card</button>
                        <% end %>
                      </div>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            <% end %>
```

Comment: Check the value of params[:expiry], the error is simply because of this `nil.split(/ \/ /)`.

Comment: The field in the form is named `expriry` instead of `expiry`. Looks like you have a simple spelling mistake in there. Also, remove the whitespaces in the regex. It should be `.split(/\//)` if your input has the format `MM/YY`.

Comment: @Lily  change name of expiry field. It is  expriry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of your `expiry` field in the form is `expriry` you have an extra `r` in there. Because of this the field you're looking at in your controller doesn't have a value so it evaluates to `nil` and you can't perform `string` methods on a `nil` object.

Change `expriry` to `expiry` in your form.

Comment: OMG... So silly!!! Thank you so much, it would take me hours to figures this out :)

Comment: You'll soon get there where these are the first things you look for. It's usually a mismatch of the parameter either on the view or controller side. Happy to help!